# Get HTML source with PHP via authenticated URL

Tags: php, url

How can I get website source with PHP, if website is using Basic Authentication?

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init("http://domain.com/password.html");
$fp = fopen("source.txt", "w");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What is the expected result? What are you actually getting?

Comment: I get empty file (source.txt)... and no errors...

Comment: You don't seem to be writing to source.txt. Perhaps you're missing a `fwrite($fp, $output);`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're missing a fwrite as PhpMyCoder suggests, curl writes to the file on curl_exec as long as CURLOPT_FILE is set with a file handle.

What might be happening is a problem with redirects: Some models of basic authentication will cause a redirect to occur and if the redirection doesn't have any HTML data to pass along that could explain your empty file.

Try adding the line

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

in with your other curl options and see if that helps.

Comment: Doesn't work, even if I add this line: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

Comment: Very strange, I ran your code locally (with the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION set) and it worked ok.  Could there be something strange going on with the destination server?

Comment: I'm trying to connect in my router on address 192.168.1.1. Is for that something different?